# Tags That Activate Only When Inside/Outside of Radius

Tags: python, bluetooth, wifi, nfc, rfid

I have a strange question and I'm not exactly sure if this is the right forum for it.
We have two cats in our home and we want to try and make an ID chip/RFID tag to put around each of their necks and code a system that only activates when it detects that either chip is inside of a radius (let's say 3 meters) IF the other chip is outside of the radius.  I assume we would need at least two sensors (in separate areas of the house) linked via wifi, bluetooth, etc.

Example:

```
radius = 3
power = 0
def feed()
    if RFID1 is in radius AND RFID2 is not in radius
        power =+ 1
    if RFID2 is in radius AND RFID1 is not in radius
        power =+ 1
    power = 0

Cards = feed()
```

not an expert by any means, but i have a feeling someone has to already come up with something like this before.
Any links or suggestions to get this project towards a reality would be greatly appreciated!

We haven't tried anything yet, this is all theoretical.  Products available on the market that we've tested have all been outsmarted by said cats.  #CatHacking

Comment: Main problem is to calculate the distance to the RFID chip. This isn't trivial. See e. g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14237110/calculate-distance-to-rfid-tag and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30660397/how-to-calculate-distance-between-rfid-reader-and-tag

Answer (score -1):

Are we talking actual radius or zone level tracking? You mention radius but maybe you can solve this by tracking room to room?. Room to room is zone-level tracking but radius tracking can be accomplished as well. Are you using UHF, LF, NFC, BLE or BT sensors? Beacons? Passive or Active RFID? If RFID are you using circular polarized antennas? There is a lot more information you may need to provide to help you attain a better approach to your problem. There is a solution that has accomplished exactly what you are saying (check out ProxiTrak) however, in your case you could:

Create a digital double of your home. Use a JavaScript Framework like Fabric.js (or in C# build your own graphic objects) that you could draw over each room (as overlay on your digital double). Associated each zone object with an interrogator (reader) IP and associated Antenna number and zone name. This way when your cat moves between zones the interrogated event from the room/radius associated sensor will let you know where ( and you can code any alerting or notification thereof) the cat's location (in general). This solution is highly relevant to in and outs you have designated for your "Radius" or "Zone".  You cover the in and outs with sensors. You need help with a little startup code let me know.